# struggling with algebra of inverted matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

i'm having some trouble with a basic linear algebra problem because the techniques for solving it aren't completely clear to me yet.

here is the question. i am supposed to solve for $X$.

$(A - AX)^{-1} = X^{-1}B$

this is the answer:

$X = (A + B^{-1})^{-1}A$

i have tried to do this a bunch of different ways, but i haven't gotten close to the correct answer. here is one example of an attempt.

$(A - AX)^{-1} = X^{-1}B$

$(A - AX)^{-1}B^{-1} = X^{-1}$

$A^{-1}B^{-1} - (AX)^{-1}B^{-1} = X^{-1}$

$A^{-1}B^{-1} - X^{-1}A^{-1}B^{-1} = X^{-1}$

$A^{-1}B^{-1} = X^{-1} + X^{-1}A^{-1}B^{-1}$

$XA^{-1}B^{-1} = I + A^{-1}B^{-1}$

$XA^{-1} = B + A^{-1}$

$X = BA + I$

i must admit that i haven't got a great grasp of the algebra techniques here. but my book didn't really explain much beyond the very basics. there is no other similar example available, so i'm struggling.

anyway, i would appreciate it very much if someone could walk me through how to solve a problem like this. thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It seems that you are using some sort of rule $(A+B)^{-1}=A^{-1}+B^{-1}$. However this is not correct. You can easily check that this is false even for simple numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert LHS and RHS of relationship

$$(A - AX)^{-1} = X^{-1}B$$

giving:

$$A-AX=B^{-1}X$$

Then

$$A=(A+B^{-1})X$$

Then...

Answer (score 2):

It's just applying basic group and ring laws:

$(A-AX)^{-1} = X^{-1}B$, so we can left multiply both sides by $(A-AX)$ so the left cancels and we get

$$I = (A-AX)X^{-1}B$$

now we use that multiplication distributes over $-$ so this equals

$$I = AX^{-1}B -AXX^{-1}B = AX^{-1}B - AB$$ we were lucky to lose one pair of $X$ in the middle; now add $AB$ to both sides

$$I+AB = AX^{-1}B$$ and left multiply by $A^{-1}$ and right multiply by $B^{-1}$ on both sides:

$$A^{-1}(I+AB)B^{-1} = X^{-1}$$

so

$$A^{-1}B^{-1} + I = X^{-1}$$ and now invert both sides to get $X$:

$$X = (A^{-1}B^{-1}+I)^{-1}$$

Comment: I type too slowly...

Answer (score 1):

Since $I=(A-AX)X^{-1}B=AX^{-1}B-AB$, $AX^{-1}B=I+AB$ so $X^{-1}=A^{-1}B^{-1}+I=A^{-1}(A+B^{-1})$. Now invert.

Answer (score 1):

$(A-AX)^{-1}=X^{-1}B$ implies that $((A-AX)^{-1})^{-1}=B^{-1}X=A-AX$, $(A+B^{-1})X=A$ and $X=(A+B)^{-1}A$